# declaring a pointer to the main window from a dialog in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

this maybe a c++ question most probely than qt. but I was finding a way to do this for 2days. but cant solve this my self. I expect some experts help in this issue. this is my question.

in my Qt application I have a main window and a dialog. in the main window it has `lineEdit_1` and in the dialog `lineEdit_2`. in the main window I have a pushButton and once it is pressed the dialog will apper. But I need to type some text in the main window's lineEdit_1 and when the pushButton is pressed I need the Dialog to apper displaying that text in it's lineEdit_2. this is how I tryed to do this. I would be very thankful in eny advice.

mainwindow.h

```
 #include"mydialog.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow, private Ui::MainWindow
{

Q_OBJECT

private:
mydialog *dia;


public:
 MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);


public slots:
void showMyDialog();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
 #include"mainwindow.h"

 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)

{
setupUi(this);

connect(pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(showMyDialog()) );
}

void MainWindow::showMyDialog(){
dia=new mydialog(this);
dia->exec();
}
```

mydialog.h

```
 #include"mainwindow.h"


 class mydialog : public QDialog, private Ui::mydialog
 {
 Q_OBJECT

 public:
  mydialog(QWidget *parent );
  MainWindow *blh;


 public slots:

 }
```

in mydialog.h if I do not add `#include"mainwindow.h"` this compiles without errors. but as in the code when i add it the compiler gives a error `error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'newMember' with no type` in the line `mydialog *dia;`

I want to add `#include"mainwindow.h"` in mydialog.h beacause then i can declair a pointer as `MainWindow *blh;` and get the text in the main window by

```
QString str=blh->lineEdit_1->text();
```

is this correct or am I doing something wrong. please someone give me in advice, or point out in eny mistake. how can I do this.

thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple answer : why not making the `mydialog` constructor take a string ?

```
mydialog::mydialog(QString str, QWidget* parent)
{
    // ...
    lineEdit_2->setText(str);
    // ...
}
```

And then, in the  main window :

```
void MainWindow::showMyDialog()
{
    mydialog dia(lineEdit_1->text(), this); // instead of new mydialog(...);
    dia->exec();
}
```

Note that you had a memory leak (`new` without `delete`). I corrected this in the showed code.

This method avoid tight relationships between the dialog and the mainwindow, thus making your code more easy to maintain.

Comment: yes this worked. but the compiler took about 10 mins to bild this :) can you point out me how to avoid the meomary leak. what was the mistake in my code. why cant we use pointers in this case. what do you mean by tight releationship. please reply, im new in qt.

Comment: Done. Sorry, I was using 'previously' in the wrong sense, fixed now.